# lm-sensors shows only 1 core temp

Tags: sensors, lm-sensors

On intel atom machine, is this perfectly normal? I thought I'd see 2 core temps - Core 0 and Core 1

```
$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +68.0°C  (crit = +99.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +55.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which CPU exactly is it? Some older Atom CPUs are single core, but most all new ones are dual core.

Check [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Atom_microprocessors) for a list of all the Atom processors and what features they support.